# Why am I getting Undefined References to any printing related functions win32?

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

Heres what my Includes look like (Linker error, so Probably nothing to do with these anyway):

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0501
#include <windows.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include "resources.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winspool.h>
```

Here is how I am trying to implement:

```
HRESULT DisplayPrintPropertySheet(HWND hWnd)
{
    HRESULT hResult;
    PRINTDLGEX pdx = {0};
    LPPRINTPAGERANGE pPageRanges = NULL;

    pPageRanges = (LPPRINTPAGERANGE) GlobalAlloc(GPTR, 10 * sizeof(PRINTPAGERANGE));
    if (!pPageRanges)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;


    pdx.lStructSize = sizeof(PRINTDLGEX);
    pdx.hwndOwner = hWnd;
    pdx.hDevMode = NULL;
    pdx.hDevNames = NULL;
    pdx.hDC = NULL;
    pdx.Flags = PD_RETURNDC | PD_COLLATE;
    pdx.Flags2 = 0;
    pdx.ExclusionFlags = 0;
    pdx.nPageRanges = 0;
    pdx.nMaxPageRanges = 10;
    pdx.lpPageRanges = pPageRanges;
    pdx.nMinPage = 1;
    pdx.nMaxPage = 1000;
    pdx.nCopies = 1;
    pdx.hInstance = 0;
    pdx.lpPrintTemplateName = NULL;
    pdx.lpCallback = NULL;
    pdx.nPropertyPages = 0;
    pdx.lphPropertyPages = NULL;
    pdx.nStartPage = START_PAGE_GENERAL;
    pdx.dwResultAction = 0;



    hResult = PrintDlgEx(&pdx);

    if ((hResult == S_OK) && pdx.dwResultAction == PD_RESULT_PRINT)
    {
        StartDocPrinter(pdx.hDC,1,NULL);
        EndDocPrinter(pdx.hDC);

        cout << "Printer Succeeeded";

    }

    if (pdx.hDevMode != NULL)
        GlobalFree(pdx.hDevMode);
    if (pdx.hDevNames != NULL)
        GlobalFree(pdx.hDevNames);
    if (pdx.lpPageRanges != NULL)
        GlobalFree(pPageRanges);

    if (pdx.hDC != NULL)
        DeleteDC(pdx.hDC);

    return hResult;
}
```

I keep getting these undefined linker errors any time I try to use `StartDoc,EndDoc,StartPage,EndPage,ect.`

Linker Errors:

```
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `StartDocPrinterA@12'|
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `EndDocPrinter@4'|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 15 warnings ===|
```

Comment: Did you link to `winspool.lib`?

Comment: yes I did link to win spool. lib

Comment: Paste the full linker line.

Answer (score 2):

Those two functions, as documented, require you to link against winspool.lib. It would seem therefore that you are not doing that.